# React-native - java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

I'm trying to build my app in three versions with different applicationIdSuffix - release (without suffix), stg and dev. The whole build process is okay and i have my apk with updated appId, but when i install and open the app it close immediately. I found error in device logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
Process: myApp.stg, PID: 13975
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:248)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:29)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:277)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1402)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1200(ReactInstanceManager.java:136)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Here is my buildVariants

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
        staging {
            initWith release
            matchingFallbacks =  ['release']
            applicationIdSuffix 'stg'
        }
        develop {
            initWith release
            applicationIdSuffix "dev"
            matchingFallbacks =  ['release']
        }

    }
```

App works without applicationIdSuffix in debug and release.

Totally idk how to handle with this. Im trying to build app with diff flavours but it ends the same. Also i updated google-service.json file with a new buildVariant.

Are there any other places when I need to change something to make things work?

Anyone had a similiar problem?